# Remove partial duplicates from table with no unique column

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have to clean up records from a table that doesn't have a primary key or a a unique constraint.

Table definition:

```
create table person(
    name text,
    staff_id integer,
    work_code text,
    location
);
```

Unsurprisingly, it contains a lot of duplicates and partial duplicates.
What is the best way to transform the records to a unique set. I don't have to care about other columns besides name and staff_id

Comment: What do you call "partial duplicates"?

Comment: @fge variations on work_code and location, I just have to keep name and staff_id

Comment: And do you actually care which values will get in the final result?

Comment: @fge I just need the name and staff_id columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you

> don't have to care about other columns besides name and staff_id

This could be your procedure to clean up the table:

1.) Create a temporary table of *unique* rows:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE p_tmp AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, staff_id)
       name, staff_id, work_code, location
FROM   person
ORDER  BY name, staff_id, work_code, location;
```

I arbitrarily pick the "first row per `(name, staff_id)` - minimum `work_code` and matching `location`.

2.) Empty table:

```
TRUNCATE person;
```

3.) Re-INSERT unique tuples:

```
INSERT INTO person SELECT * FROM p_tmp;
```

Make sure, dupes don't creep back in. Add a surrogate primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD COLUMN person_id serial PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE person ADD UNIQUE (name, staff_id);
```

**Or** just add a multi-column primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD PRIMARY KEY (name, staff_id);
```

The temporary table will be dropped at the end of the session automatically.

Of course, all of this is best done inside one [transaction](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-transactions.html), so you don't lose anything in the unlikely case that you run into a problem half way. Some clients do that automatically for a batch of SQL statements executed at once.

Comment: Surely `max` is better than `min`; make nulls the least likely to be selected.

Comment: @Ben: Neither `max()` nor `min()` will select `NULL` over **any** value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
select t.name, t.staff_id, t.work_code, t.location
from (
    select name, staff_id, work_code, location, count(*) nr
    from person
    group by name, staff_id, work_code, location
) t
where t.nr > 1;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean I need to get rid of the partial duplicate rows but keep the 1 unique row with all the other values as well. I tried distinct but it still returns all the rows

Comment: It complaints that I need to include the all the t.* columns in a group by clause. When I do that it returns no rows. I tested the sub query and the "nr" columns never contain values more than 1.